# Include the firebase-admin SDK module in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-admin

I want to use firebase-admin in angularJS but i don't know to do that.

any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Jon-Biz/FireUser) You can see the integration of angularJS with firebase.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDK is designed for use in trusted environments, such as server-side node or server-side Java. It is not meant to be directly used in client-side environments, which is where Angular is targeted.

There are valid use-cases for showing the information from the Firebase Admin SDK in a client (such as an administrative web interface). But in those cases, you will have to create your own server-side node.js API (e.g. through Express) and consume *that* in your Angular app.